# combination of Oracle database and in-memory database in java program

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, in-memory-database

I am going to enhance the performance of my program. For this purpose I am going to implement some parts of my program to be done in memory instead of database. I dont know which one is better in this regards, in-memory database or normal java data structure.For in-memory database I considered Tentimes from oracle and H2. So another question would be which solution is better for around 100 million records of data on single machine for single user? Also another question would be is the old way of database connection works fine in this way? Here is the connection that I used for oracle, What is the appropriate Driver for this purpose.

```
public static Connection getConnection(){       
        //If instance has not been created yet, create it
        if(DatabaseManager.connection == null){
            initConnection();
        }
        return DatabaseManager.connection;
    }   
    //Gets JDBC connection instance
    private static void initConnection(){           
        try{        
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               String connectionUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:" + dbName;

            DatabaseManager.connection =
                         DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"****","****");      
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){       
            System.out.println("Oracle driver is not loaded!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (SQLException e){         
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e){        
        }       
    }
public static ResultSet executeQuery(String SQL) throws SQLException
{
    CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
    ResultSet rset = null ;
    Statement st = null;
    try {
           st = DatabaseManager.getConnection().createStatement();
           rset = st.executeQuery(SQL);
           crs.populate(rset);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }finally{
        rset.close();
        st.close();
    }
    return crs;
 }
public static void executeUpdate(String SQL)
{
    try {
           Statement st = DatabaseManager.getConnection().createStatement();
           st.executeUpdate(SQL);
          // st.close();
    }

    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
 }
```

Regards.

Comment: You do realize that the operations happen in-memory on the database server too, right? I'd find it surprising if moving stuff to an in-memory database is going to make things faster, I'd rather try to find ways to optimize the interaction with your Oracle database rather than trying to work around having to do that.

Comment: I have some temporary results which is stored in database and is read from database in some other parts of my program. I am going to remove this middle process by storing temp results in memory...

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to be hugely disappointed, especially regarding the volume of records you mention. I don't know the details, but perhaps even a BigData solution is a better choice.

Comment: I am thinking of Big Data as a main solution but right now migrating to Big Data is impossible for me.